# Which encryption is recommended for own messenger

Tags: encryption, implementation, transport-security

I wrote my own messaging-app and now I would like to encrypt the data transfer between my client (app) and my server. What kind of encryption is easy to implement and can be recommended? I am very very knew to the whole encryption thing. I would love to get some hints or ideas as input.

I use TCP/IP for delivering the messages.

Comment: Note that TLS, which the answer recommends, is *not* easy to implement. However, you should not be implementing the encryption protocol/algorithms anyway, but use a library for that.

Answer (score 5):

TLS, without a doubt. Note that TLS does not imply HTTP, so you can use it with whatever TCP protocol you have.

For UDP you can use DTLS, which I believe forces the use of CTR mode to combat packet loss.

Answer (score 1):

Don't forget about authentication - encrypted communication is worth nothing if you'd let anyone in MitM position to act as encrypting proxy. When you're using TLS you should always perform proper certification path validation. I'd strongly recommend you to read [The most dangerous code in the world: validating SSL certificates in non-browser software](https://www.cs.utexas.edu/~shmat/shmat_ccs12.pdf) paper, it should help you to understand common pitfalls.

Then you should carefully pick supported protocol versions, cipher suites, and key exchange parameters to eliminate ones with known vulnerabilities, and after that verify your configuration using proper tools. You can find some of them at [OTG-CRYPST-001](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Testing_for_Weak_SSL/TLS_Ciphers,_Insufficient_Transport_Layer_Protection_(OTG-CRYPST-001)) section of OWASP Testing Guide.

Comment: An important point. While MAC validation might be enforced by the TLS protocol, certificate validation is the job of the library user, so is essentially optional.